# Trigger authorization validation manually

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, authorize-attribute

I've a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` in my website. It has some logic about the `Result` created for unathorized requests.

In some cases, I want to trigger its validation manually*. I don't know if its possible. As I haven't found how to do that, I thought that I could extract the logic to get the `Result` to a diferrent method, and call it when I want. But then I don't know how to execute the `ActionResult` (outside de controllers).

How can I do to manually execute authorize validation? If not possible, how can I do to execute an ActionResult outside a controller?

*I need to trigger it manually because some request may pass the validation (because the session is created) and then, when accessing my services, found that the session was closed by someone else. I wouldn't like to add a call to the services in `OnAuthorization` to reduce services calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if its the best, but I've found a way to get it working (still listening for better answers).

1. When I call the services and notice that the work session has expired, all I do is removing the active user in the web session.
2. My custom authorize attribute also implements `IResultFilter` and `IExceptionFilter`.
3. In both `OnResultExecuted` and `OnException` I validate the active user once more. If the session was removed, then apply the same `ActionResult` that I would apply in `OnAuthorization`.

Here is the final class:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IResultFilter, IExceptionFilter
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        ActionResult result = Validate(filterContext.HttpContext);

        if (result != null)
            filterContext.Result = result;
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        ActionResult result = Validate(filterContext.HttpContext);

        if (result != null)
            filterContext.Result = result;
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        ActionResult result = Validate(filterContext.HttpContext);

        if (result != null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = result;
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }

    public static ActionResult Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (UserActiveInSession)
            return null;

        // Different rules to build an ActionResult for this specific case.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not get Diego answer's, But Just simply answering the title, I got it to work like that, You can use it as attribute on controllers actions and also trigger it manually at any place in C# or in Razor views.

```
namespace SomeNameSpace 
{
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttributeMVC : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private readonly string[] rolesParams;
        public CustomAuthorizeAttributeMVC(params string[] roles)
        {
            this.rolesParams = roles;
        }

        public bool IsAuthorized { get {
                //Do your authorization logic here and return true if the current user has permission/role for the passed "rolesParams"
                string[] allowedRoles = new string[] {"role 1", "role 2", "role 3"};
                return allowedRoles.Intersect(rolesParams).Any(); //for the example
            }
        }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return this.IsAuthorized;
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            //...
        }
    }

    public class AuthorizeHelper
    {
        public static bool HasPermission(params string[] roles)
        {
            return new CustomAuthorizeAttributeMVC(roles).IsAuthorized;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttributeMVC("role 2")]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return Content("Authorized !");
}

public ActionResult SomeOtherAction()
{
    if(AuthorizeHelper.HasPermission("role 2"))
    {
        return Content("Authorized !");
    }
    return Content("401 Not Authorized !");

}
```

And as said, it can be used in Razor views by calling it normally

```
@if(AuthorizeHelper.HasPermission("role 2")) { 
     //... 
}
```

Thanks